# No function matches the given name and argument types - PGCrypto

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to use the library Django Pgcrypto Extensions.

The library seems to install fine and is in my site-packages.

However I try to run a given command that queries my database and will run the PGCrypto decrypt function, and I get this error:

```
function pgp_sym_decrypt(character varying, unknown) does not exist
```

However I check my Postgresql database to see what functions are available, and I see this:

```
 nspname |        proname        |      params       
---------+-----------------------+-------------------
 public  | pgp_sym_encrypt       | text, text
 public  | pgp_sym_encrypt_bytea | bytea, text
 public  | pgp_sym_encrypt       | text, text, text
 public  | pgp_sym_encrypt_bytea | bytea, text, text
 public  | pgp_sym_decrypt       | bytea, text
 public  | pgp_sym_decrypt_bytea | bytea, text
 public  | pgp_sym_decrypt       | bytea, text, text
 public  | pgp_sym_decrypt_bytea | bytea, text, text
```

I created the extension in Postgres (for the database I specifically want to use the extension with), etc.

So what would be causing this error?

Is there some step or configuration issue that I didn't do? As far as I can tell, PGCrypto is installed, the functions are in the database, and it should work when called.

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to store the encrypted data into a bytea column, not a text column. You might be able to cast it to bytea from text:

```
pgp_sym_decrypt(area_code::bytea,'Password')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run for you schema:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;
```